# How to make edit text not editable but clickable in JAVA

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Is it possible to make `EditText` clickable but not editable.

I don't want it to be editable (Neither should the keyboard come up nor should we be able to change the hint)

Actually I want to use Edit text simply as an image with a hint (which cannot be changed). I know the actual way was to use an `ImageView` and one `TextView`, but I want it to try with `EditText` because I'll then be using only one view instead of 2. Also every thing is dynamic so no XML.

For the above requirement the solution in XML is `android:editable="false"` but I want to use this in Java.

But,

If I use :-

```
et.setEnabled(false);
```

or

```
 et.setKeyListener(null);
```

It makes the `EditText` not EDITABLE but at the same time it makes it non clickable as well.

Comment: How about setting `et.setClickable(true)` ? It might work.

Comment: already tried.... but didn't work... any other thoughts

Comment: maybe try to use relative layout and put an empty rectangle or something ON TOP of the edittext, and try the clickable thing on the rect..

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The trick here is :-

```
et.setFocusable(false);
et.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: but if you had copied some value from any field you can paste that value hear by pressing lang tap and paste.. any idea how to remove

Comment: @ANinJa you can set the long clickable to false, i.e., et.setLongClickable(false);

Comment: Hmm, the cursor is highlighted in a weird way on click / longclick... But I don't have a better approach. :/

Comment: Perfect! you might need to add et.setLongClickable(false) to avoid copy/paste as well

Comment: You should avoid setting focusable = false because this makes the EditText unreachable for accessibility users that use keyboard navigation instead use `focusableInTouchMode`

Answer (score 30):

As `editable` is deprecated. you can use `android:inputType` as **none** in designing xml or as **InputType.TYPE_NULL** in coding.

> Designing XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/edt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:text="EditText"/>
```

> Coding

```
edt.setClickable(true);
edt.setFocusable(false);
edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

And below is the click event of `edittext`

```
edt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"edt click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 25):

you can set `EditText` by using java code as fallowing :-

```
edittext.setFocusable(false);
edittext.setClickable(true);
```

or by using below code in XML file for `EditText`.

```
android:editable="false" 
android:inputType="none"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this..

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to make edittext not editable in xml.And for clickable event you can use **setOnTouchListener()** event to do the same thing as like..

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //do your stuff here..
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` is also required (`android:focusable="false"` alone doesn't work)
in Android O. At least, in DP2.

Answer (score 8):

**`Edittext` enable and disable for the edit like this**

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findviewby(R.id.edittext);
```

> Through java code

```
edit.setEnabled(false); //non editable
edit.setEnabled(true); //editable
```

> Through xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/otp_mpin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:editable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

`android:editable` is deprecated but you can do stg like below:

```
android:editable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

I used the cade above for edittexts which i use pickers to set data in. You can use input layout with this.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020, if you also care about accessibility, you should avoid setting `et.setFocusable(false);` since that will make the EditText not reachable using Keyboard navigation.

Here is my solution:

Kotlin

```
editText.isFocusableInTouchMode = false

editText.isLongClickable = false //this will prevent copy and paste

editText.setOnClickListener {
   // handle the click
   // this will automatically make the edittext clickable = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me none of the answers resulted in a completely working solution.

Showcase of my fix https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUA4Cuxfdqc

**Guide (noob-friendly)**, please note the few comments in the code.

Create a Java class for a custom `EditText` called *EditTextDispatched.java*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

/**
 * @author Martin Pfeffer
 * @see <a href="https://celox.io">https://celox.io</a>
 */
public class EditTextDispatched extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    private static final String TAG = "DispatchingEditText";

    private boolean editable = true;

    public EditTextDispatched(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextDispatched(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EditTextDispatched(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    // get the current state
    public boolean isEditable() {
        return editable;
    }

    // set your desired behaviour
    public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
        this.editable = editable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (editable) {
            // default behaviour of an EditText
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }

        // achieve the click-behaviour of a TextView (it's cuztom)
        ((RelativeLayout) getParent()).onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Reference the `EditTextDispatched` in your xml (you will have to alter the pgk-name):

```
  <io.celox.brutus.EditTextDispatched
    android:id="@+id/row_field_value"
    style="@style/row_field_text_display"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/sample_field_value" />
```

To invoke:

```
private void changeEditTextBehaviour(EditTextDispatched value, boolean editable) {
    value.setEditable(editable);
    value.setEnabled(editable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered but to give a more current (i.e. 2018) answer here is the setup I use to achieve the requested (i.e. non-input or editable) effect:

```
    val etUserLoc: EditText = themedEditText(R.style.Pale_Blue_Text_Bold_13) {
                id = R.id.et_comp_user_keys_var_user_location
                inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
                isClickable = true
                isFocusable = false
                textColor = resources.getColor(R.color.magenta)  // overrides the default theme color
                text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(resources.getString(R.string.loc_swakopmund))
            }.lparams(width = matchConstraint, height = matchParent) {   }
```

Yes, this is ANKO since I no longer use XML in any of my Android Projects. The 'inputType' takes care of the 'isEditable' deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to disable user input and show soft keyboard at the same time.

```
textView.apply {
    filters = arrayOf(InputFilter { _, _, _, _, _, _ -> "" })
    setOnLongClickListener { true }
    isCursorVisible = false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also do `android:inputMethod="@null"` in your `EditText` and it will not show the cursor or the keyboard and then you can easily grasp the click through setting listener.